# Output of a sequence (Collatz) in Display and as a Textfile

Tags: python, sage

The following snippet gives me a **comma-separated** list in the display:

```
X = 19     # Start
N = 7      # Length
def f(x, n):
    yield x
    for k in range(0, n):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            x = x / 2
        else:
            x = 3*x + 1
        yield x
print(", ".join(map(str, f(X, N))))
f = file('collatz\N.txt','w')  # gives an empty file and is not named correctly
# f.write(str(f(X,N))  Does not work
```

How can I have that **line-separated**  (like at default) as a good named textfile, like `collatz19.txt` ?

*So the display-output is ok. I need the textfile-output _too_, and do no know the commands.*

Comment: Perhaps join around a line feed: `print("\n".join(map(str, f(X, N))))`

Comment: Maybe replace th comma by a new line ?

Comment: btw Your code could be improved by using integer division: `x = x // 2`

Comment: Yes ok. But I need the output as a textfile and I do not know how to create.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried that attempts to write to a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to write to the file:

```
# Write the whole file in one string
with open('collatz\N.txt','w') as fn:
    one_string = "\n".join(map(str, f(X, N)))
    fn.write(one_string + '\n')
```

or write to the file a line at a time:

```
with open(r'collatz\Ng.txt','w') as fn:
    gen = f(X, N)
    for line in gen:
        fn.write(str(line)+'\n')
```

Comment: Thx, I used `with open('collatz{0}.txt'.format(X),'w') as fn: ....`